# TV series about a man guided by another man with a sort of calculator

Tags: story-identification, tv

When I was little I used to watch a TV series, not quite regularly, but it managed to stick in my memories. The problem is I can't remember the title.

It was done probably in the 90s, but I'm not sure about this. However, something that can help figuring this out, is that it was about a man **guided by another man with a sort of calculator and a cigar**.

**This "guide" called his calculator with a weird name, something like Ziggie**, but I cannot remember the exact name. Anyway, this series was peculiar because of this guide, who, if I'm not mistaken, could **walk through obstacles**.

Does it ring any bells?

Comment: The calculator name was "Ziggy"... Close enough.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The show is called [Quantum Leap](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096684/).

> The show's premise and the pattern of each episode is established in the first episode.  Sam appears in the past with no memory of who he is or how he got there. Referred to frequently throughout the series as a "swiss-cheesed brain", Sam's partial amnesia prevents him from remembering most of the details of his own life; all he knows is that he's not who everyone in the past seems to think he is. Rear Admiral Al Calavicci (Dean Stockwell), a senior naval officer, Naval Aviator and Sam's best friend, appears to him as a hologram and explains that Sam is the victim of a time travel experiment that went "a little kaka." Now Sam is lost in time, and his colleagues are unable to bring him back to his own time.

<sub>[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Leap_%28TV_series%29)</sub>

Ziggy was the artificial intelligent computer that ran the project and helps Sam figure out why he traveled to that particular time and place, so he can "put things right that once went wrong".

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you. I'll accept as soon as I'm allowed to. :)

Comment: I saw this movie once...there was an old man, and this boy, and they had these kind of laser swords, and there was this giant, walking dog man. They had to rescue this princess from some kind of a space station...or was it a moonbase?

Comment: @LarsTech: I think Chris is insinuating that Quantum Leap is familiar enough that you should have recognized it.

Comment: @LarsTech Quantum Leap was very popular for a time, so (I think) that's supposed to be a joke making Star Wars sound obscure

Comment: @KeithThompson OK, my bad.  But the OP is from Italy, so the show might not be as obvious in that country as it would be in the US.

Comment: My first reaction to this question was to feel old.  I realized that for my little brother, who was born in 1990, this show is probably as hazy a memory as the question describes.

Comment: Honestly I don't see why if someone remembers this TV series, I should do the same. Not all we remember the same things.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens you are describing Space Balls right?